# Can't select specific relationship columns with eloquent's with method

Tags: php, laravel

I want to improve the resolution times of my backend axios calls and so I'm trying to use with method special syntax for selecting specific columns, but for some reason category field is returning null.

In my method:

```
$venues = Venue::select(['id','name','lat','lng'])->with('category:id,title')->take(10)->get();
```

My venue relationship:

```
public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\VenueCategory', 'venuecategory_id');
    }
```

and VenueCategory

```
public function venue()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Venue', 'venue_id');
    }
```

The resulting venue payload is like this (notice category is null)

```
Object { id: 1, name: "El Pimpi", lat: "36.7219260", lng: "-4.8594939", category: null}
```

Venue migration:

```
Schema::create('venues', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('venuecategory_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('venuecategory_id')->references('id')->on('venuecategories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->index()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->text('openingTimes')->nullable();
            $table->decimal('lng', 10, 7);
            $table->decimal('lat', 10, 7);
            $table->boolean('isConfirmed')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('isHot')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('isVisible')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('isFeatured')->default(0);
            $table->timestamp('lastScrapeForContacts')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

VenueReview migration:

```
Schema::create('venuereviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('venue_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('venue_id')->references('id')->on('venues')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->integer('rating');
            $table->text('body')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('isVisible')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('isFeatured')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('isConfirmed')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify columns in a Laravel query and need to get a relationship, you also need to get the column that the relationship uses, or else it won't have the data to make the relationship. The child models are queried after the original model is retrieved. Add the column, and it will work:

```
$venues = Venue::select(['id','name','lat','lng','venuecategory_id'])->with('category:id,title')->take(10)->get();
```